# Conditional subquery in SELECT statement

Tags: sqlite, join, conditional-statements, subquery

I'm trying to achieve the following here.

I've got 3 tables:

1. blocks
2. items
3. ingredients

I query ingredients and depending on the result, I want to subquery or join some columns from blocks or items.

I managed to conditional subselect 1 column (`name`) in my select statement but if I want to select more I than one column, e.g. `SELECT name, material_id`, I get the following error:

> Only a single result allowed for a
>   SELECT that is part of an expression

I've seen many similar cases here on SO but can't manage to get this right.

```
SELECT
    `crafting_recipes`.`ingredient_id`, `crafting_recipes`.`ingredient_table`, 
    CASE
        WHEN
            `crafting_recipes`.`ingredient_table` = 'blocks' THEN 
                (SELECT `name` FROM `blocks` WHERE `id` = `crafting_recipes`.`ingredient_id`)
        ELSE 
            (SELECT `name` FROM `items` WHERE `id` = `crafting_recipes`.`ingredient_id`)
    END
FROM 
    `crafting_recipes`
WHERE
    `crafting_recipes`.`result_id` = 15 AND
    `crafting_recipes`.`result_table` = "blocks"
```

Since selecting multiple columns in a subselect isn't supported, what would be the correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it along these lines to avoid the repeated correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT
  cr.`ingredient_id`, 
  cr.`ingredient_table`, 
  CASE
    WHEN
        cr.`ingredient_table` = 'blocks' THEN 
            b.`name`
    ELSE 
        i.`name`
  END as `name`
FROM
 `crafting_recipes` cr
  LEFT JOIN `blocks` b on b.`id` = cr.`ingredient_id`
  LEFT JOIN `items` i on i.`id` = cr.`ingredient_id`
WHERE
  cr.`result_id` = 15 AND
  cr.`result_table` = "blocks"
```

Comment: You probably need OUTER JOINS here.

Comment: Your method works and is cleaner but it doesn't allow for multiple results. Do you have a solution for that? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "multiple results"?  Subselects in the select clause are only allowed to return exactly one value.  This method works properly in that if more than one row matches the outer join you get more than one row as a result.

Comment: @Julian - `left join` is shorthand for `left outer join`.  It is an outer join.

Comment: Donnie: I would like to select multiple columns from either blocks, or items. I see that that isn't supported, what do you recommend?

Comment: @richard - one case statement per column.  Its ugly, but that's SQL.